# Ionic3 API Authentication

Tags: api, authentication, ionic3

#### AuthService

```
loginCheckUri: string = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login_check';
login(username:string,password:string) {

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let body = new URLSearchParams();
    body.set('username', username);
    body.set('password', password);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(this.loginCheckUri, body, { headers: headers }).subscribe(res => {
        resolve(res.json());
        console.log('success');
      }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
        console.log('error: ',err);
      });
    })
  }
```

#### LoginPage.ts

```
signIn() {
      this.authProvider.login(this.user.email,this.user.password)
      .then((res) => { this.navCtrl.push(HomePage); })
      .catch((err)=>{console.log('error');});
  }
```

> I got response successfully, **Status Code: 200** and also the **Token** but
> I got error in the console,

## Response

[image: Response screenshot]

## Console Error

[image: Console Error screenshot]

Comment: Its a CORS issue.. you need to verify if your server side has CORS set up correctly

Comment: how can i check the `CORS`, please??

Comment: depends on your server side tech read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Thanks man it was `CORS` issue i installed a `Chrome Extension` and it solved.